# mysql: logging specific user logins

Tags: mysql, logging

I'm looking for a stored procedure or something to log user-logins to mysql.
Users will have to be in a positive list.

I need to log user, login time, ip/hostname and query ( query not essential, but a nice-to-have).

My major problem is that I cannot do it via general query log, as is generates +23Gb of log per instance/day (i have 18 instances) and I don't have capacity for it.

I was thinking somewhat in lines of stored procedures, but cannot get my head around it, but not sure if it is the right way to go about it.

Capacity expansion is not an option.

Platform is:

- CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611
- mysql-community-server-5.6.36-2

Any thoughts on how to solve my issue are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for [the mysql init_connect system variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html) :

> A string to be executed by the server for each client that connects. The string consists of one or more SQL statements, separated by semicolon characters.

So basically you want to create a table where logins will be logged, and set the `init_connect` system variable to something like :

```
INSERT INTO my_logging_audit
SELECT USER(), NOW()
WHERE USER() IN ('foo', 'bar');
```